# Delete double entries

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have several entries in my DB, lets say its a book library which contains books by people.

E.g.

```
Bookname A - UserA
Bookname B - UserB
```

I now imported some Books of the same name, and made "UserC" as their owner.

So now I have

```
Bookname A - UserA
Bookname B - UserB
Bookname A - UserC
Bookname C - UserC
```

How can I delete only those entries, where owner is UserC and the bookname is already owned by another person that is not UserC?

My result should be:

```
Bookname A - UserA
Bookname B - UserB
Bookname C - UserC
```

THank you!

Comment: How is decided which entry is the correct one and should be kept? (Could be by ID or by insertion date, for example.)

Comment: In this case we can assume that the one with UserC is the one which is wrong added to the database, if there is already a book from UserA for example. 

P.S. Due to some given circumstances, its not possible to use the bookname as primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subselect based on having for get the name with more entry and the filter the delete for user = 'C'

```
 delete from my_table 
 where bookname in ( 
    select Bookname 
    from my_table 
    group by Boookname
    having count(*) > 1)
and User = 'C';
```

Comment: **where name in** - what does this indicate? Did you mean "bookname" ?

Comment: @MrKayodoubleu  yes is bookanme

Answer (score 0):

The answer with the inner select cannot work, as it uses the target of the update in the FROM clause. MySQL does not allow that.
But with a delete join, this is possible. My solution is probably not the most elegant, but it works:

```
DELETE t1 FROM book_table t1 LEFT JOIN book_table t2 ON t1.book = t2.book AND t2.user <> 'C' WHERE t1.user = 'C' AND t2.user IS NOT NULL;
```

Better test it first, with a select instead of the delete, so you can see it's going to delete the correct entries.